# Does Rikulo support mysql database?

Tags: mysql, dart, rikulo

I know rukilo is an UI framework for Dart language but I wonder if it supports to use Mysql? And if it is, how to connect mysql with Dart? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We are developing Rikulo ORM to simplify the database access (but it is not opened yet). The first version will be built on top of WebSQL (SQLite) and IndexedDB. We do have a plan to bridge it to the backend server such as MySQL. Of course, there are some security and performance challenges to deal with.

Comment: Does this mean Rikulo ORM is a server-side Dart library?

Comment: We're shifting the focus to more on the server side and NoSQL. We almost rewrote everything since JPA style is too heavy.

Comment: Thank you, Tom.

After reading other parts of the server-side Dart. It's clearly to me that Dart needs a DB/Datastore connection layer first.